# Missing Controller - Cake PHP (New installation)

Tags: php, apache, cakephp

I have installed cakephp in document root folder and renamed it to todo. So the complete path is `(C:\localhost\todo)`. I am able to run the index.php perfectly fine (all tabs are green).

I created the 'todo' example application from the book 'Beginning CAKE PHP - Novoice to Professional'. I keep getting the error 'MISSING CONTROLLER' even though I have the `items_controller.php` file. I am thinking for some reason the application does not know where the controller file is present.
The complete error is :

> Missing Controller Error: ItemsController could not be found. Error:
>   Create the class ItemsController below in file:
>   app\Controller\ItemsController.php

```
<?php
  class ItemsController extends AppController {

  }
```

I have `.htacess` and `index.php` files in respective folder
Can someone please help.

Comment: The error is pretty much useful, what you need is to create the controller file as stated by the error message

Answer (score 1):

Controller class names are plural, CamelCased, and end in Controller. So your controller name should be `ItemsController.php` not `items_controller.php`. See [here](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers.html) for more info on Controllers.

```
class ItemsController extends AppController { 
    //class code here
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I have tried renaming to the ItemsController.php but still the same error.

Comment: @ComradeRaj did you create your controller inside::  app\Controller\  ..?

Comment: Yes its inside C:\localhost\todo\app\Controller

Comment: And contents of Controller are:<?
class ItemsController extends AppController {
 var $name = 'Items';
 var $scaffold;
 }
 ?>